# getopt doesn't work as expected under MacOS with short options

Tags: bash, macos, getopt

I have the following command: `command.sh bar -b=FOO`

I'm trying to parse it with the following: `getopt "m::b::" "$@"`

Under Linux, the result is: `-b =FOO -- command.sh bar`

Under MacOS, the result is: `-- command.sh bar -b=FOO`. So it is not parsed at all. I tried `-bFOO` and `-b FOO` but with the same result, it was not parsed.

How to fix that? I need a cross-platform bash solution that will work both on Mac and Linux.

Comment: The `getopt` command you are using under MacOS is probably the default one (FreeBSD), which is not the same as under GNU/Linux. Either install the GNU/Linux `getopt` with MacPorts or Homebrew, or have a look at the FreeBSD `getopt` man pages and adapt your code.

Comment: Could you explain better, with examples? The comment "read the manual" doesn't make much sense. In the man page you've referred to, I see "If an individual character is followed by two colons, then the option argument is optional". This is precisely my case. I tried passing the argument as `-bFOO` and `-b FOO` but had no luck at all, it was not parsed.

Comment: You could look into writing your script in python or perl or some such... or indeed implementing getopt in one of those 2.

Comment: What do you see if you type `man -M /usr/share/man getopt`? And `getopt --version`?

Comment: The macOS version doesn't allow options to come after positional (non-option) arguments; it looks like you have "command.sh" in the argument list (which it shouldn't be if it's the script name). Options first is the traditional unix convention, but the GNU people decided they should be allowed in any order (except not after `--`), and wrote all their parsers to work that way. Also, even under the GNU version, the `=` delimiter should only be used with long options.

Comment: Gordon, you're correct, I had another sub-command but deleted it in the sample. Sorry for misleading you. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getopt` is an external utility & version specific, so you need to match the version on Mac with the one you are used to on Linux.
Rather, use [getopts](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html) which is a builtin. It's portable & works in any POSIX shell right out-of-the-box.

##### Example:

```
while getopts "m::b::" opt; do
  case ${opt} in
    m) # do 'm' thing
      echo M
      ;;
    b) # do 'b' thing
      echo B
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: You may precise: `getopts` is a [tag:bash] *builtin*, so don't depend on bash version, not on intallation (GNU getopt vs FreeBSD getopt).

Comment: This is the best option in my case, thanks. Could you also mention in your answer that the `OPTIND=2` is required in my case (I updated my question after you posted your answer).

Comment: @AlexanderPravdin it's also a `zsh` builtin. Zsh is the default shell on macOS. It's nearly the same as bash but the "nearly" part may cause you some problems, if you are not aware of zsh.